# Searching in MongoDB database by multiple conditions

Tags: node.js, arrays, database, mongodb

I'm new to mongodb and have this question.  I have document like this where project is array of project IDs.

```
[{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "62c2e94e65f32725f8f62b79"
    },
    "project": [1,4,5],
    "organization": "test",
    "name": "john",
    "surname": "doe"
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "62c409eb242b0509c4b5d891"
  },
  "project": [16,2],
  "organization": "test1",
  "name": "john1",
  "surname": "doe1"
}]
```

For searching the elements by organization I use this expression and it works ok
User.find({organization: {$eq: data.org}})
How can I expand my expression so it search by organization and specific ID from the project array.
For example I want to find user who work in organization Test and who works on project with ID 16.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use comma to separate:

```
User.find({organization: "test1", project: 16})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vT5w0VYoHHQ)

Comment: Thanks  for the answer. So now when I get a document as result I want to  show on my page the name and surname from that document.  How can I do this? Should  I keep the ObjectId from the document and use it as condition in my next search? How can I reach now the name and surname?

Comment: Try [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/40Q0AjQmfY-)